# How do I adjust a size of a box and it's opacity based on what webpage is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three boxes that I would like to change it's width, height, and opacity based on what webpage is loaded. I am unsure what I need to change in my javascript, so any help would be really helpful.

```html
<html>
  <body onload="setDark()">
    <a href="siteone.html">
      <div class="firstbox" id="fBox"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="sitetwo.html">
      <div class="secondbox" id="sBox"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="sitethree.html">
      <div class="thirdbox" id="tBox"></div>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function setDark() {
  var currentPage = window.location.href;
  var boxOne = document.getElementById("fBox");
  var boxTwo = document.getElementById("sBox");
  var boxThree = document.getElementById("tBox");
  if (currentPage === "siteone.html") {
    document.getElementById("fBox").style.width = "100px";
    document.getElementById("fBox").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("fBox").style.opacity = 0.6;
  }
  if (currentPage === "secondpage.html") {
    document.getElementById("sBox").style.width = "100px";
    document.getElementById("sBox").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("sBox").style.opacity = 0.6;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tBox").style.width = "100px";
    document.getElementById("tBox").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("tBox").style.opacity = 0.6;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dpvumw0o/

Comment: The href should be the whole url, not just the filename.  Try if (currentPage.endsWith("... ?

Comment: I edited that into the if statements and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing window.location.href, the full url of the page to file strings.

If you don't have any folder depth you could user window.location.pathname instead and add a slash in your comparisons.

```
window.location.pathname === '/siteone.html'
```

You could also simply check if the url ends with your strings using a regular expression:

```
/siteone\.html$/.test(window.location.href)
```

If you don't like regular expressions

```
window.location.href.indexOf('siteone.html') > -1
```

Finally you could use the string method endsWith (however it isn't supported in internet explorer):

```
window.location.href.endsWith('siteone.html')
```

Comment: I added in an endsWith() to the if statement and it still does not work for me.

Comment: Never mind, my original code had extra "" which caused the whole thing not to work. I have marked your solution as correct. Thank you.